# PHP : Call to a member function execute() on boolean Error

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code :

```
    public function getTypeByID($typeId) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT type_id, description FROM type WHERE type_id = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $typeId);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id_type, $description);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $type = array();
        $type["type_id"] = $id_type;
        $type["description"] = $description;
        $stmt->close();
        return $type;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I got this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean.

I checked all topics that talk about it but nothing works for me.

I tried to execute the query on Mysql (PhpMyAdmin) and it works.

My type table structure :

[image]

Any idea.

Comment: change `type_id = ?` to `type_id = :i`

Comment: Main idea is to check errors.

Comment: @atoms they're using mysqli_ here, not PDO.

Comment: chedk your connection and post more code and the class

Comment: it looks like PDO to me, how can you tell? I thought it was an issue with how they are binding the param. Your right though, check connection, provide error message/log.

Comment: @atoms easy `bind_param` and `bind_*`, mysqli. `bindParam` is PDO, look those up ;-)

Comment: Instead of `return Null` do `die(mysqli_stmt_err($stmt));`

Comment: Asking a question and then disappearing isn't nice though

Comment: this is missing too much code, I'm out.

Comment: @AlivetoDie the code is not going to the else part it is failing earlier... My guess is `$this->conn` has a problem...

Comment: i got always $stmt false and the error on next line

Comment: Try this:- `public function getTypeByID($typeId) {
 if($this->conn){
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT type_id, description FROM type WHERE type_id = ? ");
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $typeId);
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
   $stmt->bind_result($id_type, $description);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $type = array();
   $type["type_id"] = $id_type;
   $type["description"] = $description;
   $stmt->close();
   return $type;
  } else {
   die(mysqli_stmt_err($stmt));
  }
 }else{
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $this->conn->connect_error);
 }
}`

Comment: ok i'm going to try it.

Comment: got this :Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in $stmt->bind_param("i", $typeId);

Answer (score 1):

Your sql did name the table, but I just had an instance of this same error that brought me to this page.

Calling the "database name" or a non-existant table instead of the "table name" in the SQL also generates this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because *type* is a reserved word in MySQL. 
See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html
Try to change the table name to smth else.

Comment: Ok I will change it

Comment: Ok, try to print out the mysql error with :
if ( false===$stmt ) {

  die('prepare() failed: ' .$mysqli->error);
}
 
before if ($stmt->execute()) {

Comment: I did it and i got Mysql Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now So i checked all my functions and I found that I didn't close $stmt before I made a new query so I close it and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`type` is a reserved word for MySQL.
To resolve this, you need to add single quote in your statement.

Example

```
SELECT 'type_id', 'description' FROM 'type' WHERE 'type_id' .........
```